# DateTime.Now.ToString() format in Linux (Docker) different from Windows

Tags: linux, datetime, docker, .net-core

I am trying to understand why `ToString()` behave different in Linux.

Source code:

```
using System;

namespace datetime
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Cultura {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTime raw: {DateTime.Now}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTime.Now: {DateTime.Now.ToString("o")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTime.UtcNow: {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTimeOffset.Now: {DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("o")}");

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-CO");
            Console.WriteLine($"\nCultura {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTime raw: {DateTime.Now}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTime.Now: {DateTime.Now.ToString("o")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTime.UtcNow: {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DateTimeOffset.Now: {DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("o")}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Windows has its locale set as `es-CO` and when you run `datetime` net core console application, it shows year with four digits

[image]

Docker image (in Linux) has the same [culture es-CO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue/505424#505424).

```
root@35469504242b:/app# cat /etc/default/locale
LANG=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_ALL=es_CO.UTF-8
```

And it has environment variables setup on ~/.bashrc

```
root@35469504242b:/app# env 
LANG=es_CO.UTF-8
LC_ALL=es_CO.UTF-8
root@35469504242b:/app# env
LC_ALL=es_CO.UTF-8
HOSTNAME=35469504242b
ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
PWD=/app
HOME=/root
ASPNETCORE_VERSION=2.1.2
DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Locale:

```
root@35469504242b:/app# locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_CO.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=es_CO.UTF-8
```

When you run the net core application in Linux, year is presented with only **two digits**.

Why `ToString()` shows different result under Linux? Is there a fix to behave the same?

[image]

Comment: is it possible to use a format in ToString() Like ToString("%H:%M:%S)?

Comment: Look at the values of the [`ShortDatePattern`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern?view=netframework-4.7.2) and the [`ShortTimePattern`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern?view=netframework-4.7.2), because that is what `DateTime.ToString()` will use. In the end I would also suggest to use the `DateTime.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)` overload and set the patter explicitly, that you want. Might be a diff. of how the cultures are defined on Windows vs Linux.

Comment: Additionally, the above mentioned patterns _might_ even be user-settable through the OS (not sure though).

Comment: I could not find a way to setup date format in Linux. I also think I must avoid doing it since I may not be authorized to change such setting in some production environments. I have noticed that `DateTime` has correct values for day, month and year. It works fine despite outputting two digits on Linux console. Anyway to fix issues in date formatting with ToString() in my NET Core web application I had to configure date format with `UseRequestLocalization`: https://pastebin.com/fMGJG26m